# Extracting field from last row of given table using sed

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I would like to write a bash script to extract a field in the last row of a table.  I will illustrate by example.  I have a text file containing tables with space delimited fields like ...

```
Table 1 (foobar)
num  flag  name   comments
1    ON    Frank  this guy is frank
2    OFF   Sarah  she is tall
3    ON    Ahmed  who knows him

Table 2 (foobar)
num  flag  name   comments
1    ON    Mike   he is short
2    OFF   Ahmed  his name is listed twice
```

I want to extract the first field in the last row of `Table1`, which is `3`.  Ideally I would like to be able to use any given table's title to do this. There are guaranteed carriage returns between each table.  What would be the best way to accomplish this, preferably using sed and grep?

Comment: Why do you want to use `sed` and `grep`?  `awk` is *made* to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Mostly for learning purposes but also for consistency's sake. And also so it can be ported to machine's that don't necessarily have awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk is perfect for this, print the first field in the last row for each record:

```
$ awk '!$1{print a}{a=$1}END{print a}' file
3
2
```

Just from the first record:

```
$ awk '!$1{print a;exit}{a=$1}' file
3
```

---

**Edit:**

For a given table title:

```
$ awk -v t="Table 1" '$0~t{f=1}!$1&&f{print a;f=0}{a=$1}END{if (f) print a}' file
3

$ awk -v t="Table 2" '$0~t{f=1}!$1&&f{print a;f=0}{a=$1}END{if (f) print a}' file
2
```

Comment: +1 indeed, though the *perfect* answer wouldn't hardcode the 3-column requirement :-) Can't think of an elegant way yet though!

Comment: @cbuckley I'd do  `$ awk '!$1{print a}{a=$1}END{print a}' file`

Comment: @sudo_O You beat me to the punch and posted your 2nd answer as I was editing my problem description. I was just mentioning that the number of fields should be dynamic because of this comments field having spaces.  Thanks for your excellent answer!

Comment: How would you answer change if you did not know if this was the first record or not, and you simply wanted to go off the table's title?

Answer (score 2):

This sed line seems to work for your sample.

```
table='Table 2'
sed -n "/$table"'/{n;n;:next;h;n;/^$/b last;$b last;b next;:last;g;s/^\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/p;}' file
```

Explanation: When we find a line matching the table name in $table, we skip that line, and the next (the field labels). Starting at :next we push the current line into the hold space, get the next line and see if it is blank or the end of the file, if not we go back to :next, push the current line into hold and get another. If it is blank or EOF, we skip to :last, pull the hold space (the last line of the table) into pattern space, chop out all but the first field and print it.

Comment: Wowwwww ... I'd like to give this one a +2 for solving this using sed. I can definitely see why awk is the preferred method in this problem's case.

Comment: I'm a big fan of sed, but awk is usually better for this kind of thing. Still, it's fun to try to make sed do it.

Answer (score 2):

Just read each block as a record with each line as a field and then print the first sub-field of the last field of whichever record you care about:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/^Table 1/{split($NF,a," "); print a[1]}' file
3

$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/^Table 2/{split($NF,a," "); print a[1]}' file
2
```

Answer (score -1):

Better tool to that is awk!
Here is a kind legible code:

```
awk '{
    if(NR==1) {
        row=$0;
        next;
    }

    if($0=="") {
        $0=row;
        print $1;
    } else {
        row=$0;
    }
} END {
    if(row!="") {
        $0=row;
        print $1;
    }
}' input.txt
```

Comment: I agree. Wasn't me though. Thank you for your answer anyways.

Comment: Wasn't me either, but the awk community are a picky bunch; it seems the terser the better. (EDIT: found [the article I was looking for](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).)

Comment: I agree with jyzuz. People often down-vote without giving a reason.

Comment: @user2150250 From the question I undestood that you want to print the first field of the last row of all the tables, isn't so?

Comment: @jyzuz No, I only wanted to print that field from a specific table given that table's title.